# Error when seeding data in ASP.NET Core Web API: "The value of 'AppUserRole.UserId' is unknown"

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

Thanks in advance. I am encountering an error while attempting to seed data in my ASP.NET Core Web API application using ASP.NET Core Identity.

The error I get is:

> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'API.Data.DataContext'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'AppUserRole.UserId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

I get this error after creating a migration then running `dotnet run` to run the API for the first time and seed data to the database. The complete stack trace of the error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'API.Data.DataContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'AppUserRole.UserId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.PrepareToSave()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetEntriesToSave(Boolean cascadeChanges)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'AppUserRole.UserId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.PrepareToSave()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetEntriesToSave(Boolean cascadeChanges)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
fail: Program[0]
      An error occurred during migration
      System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'AppUserRole.UserId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.PrepareToSave()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetEntriesToSave(Boolean cascadeChanges)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user, String password)
         at API.data.Seed.SeedUsers(UserManager`1 userManager, RoleManager`1 roleManager) in C:\Users\augustine\Desktop\Angular\GardenEasy\api\Data\Seed.cs:line 54
         at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\augustine\Desktop\Angular\GardenEasy\api\Program.cs:line 48
```

To provide a more detailed context and help troubleshoot this issue, here are some additional details:

The `AppUserRole` class is responsible for creating a many-to-many relationship between an `AppUser` and an `AppRole`. It inherits from the `IdentityUserRole<int>` class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace API.Entities
{
    public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public AppRole Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data seeding is performed using a `Seed` class, which utilizes the `UserManager<AppUser>` and `RoleManager<AppRole>` services. The seeding process reads user seed data from a JSON file and creates both user and role entries. The `Member` role is added to each user, and a special `admin` user is created with both `Admin` and `Moderator` roles:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using API.Data;
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.data
{
    public class Seed
    {
        public static async Task SeedUsers(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager)
        {
            // check if we already have users in db
            if (await userManager.Users.AnyAsync()) return; //stop method execution

            //no users in db, read user seed data json file
            var userData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/AppUserSeedData.json");
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AppUser>>(userData);

            var roles = new List<AppRole> {
                new AppRole {Name = "Member"},
                new AppRole {Name = "Admin"},
                new AppRole {Name = "Moderator"}
            };

            //seed roles and users
            // ForEach does not understand asynchronous delegates. So the body of the 
            //ForEach will be run concurrently, and Entity Framework does not support concurrent asynchronous access.
            //Change the ForEach to a foreach, and you should be good:
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                user.UserName = user.UserName.ToLower();
                //cast date type to utc
                user.Registered = DateTime.SpecifyKind(user.Registered, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                user.LastActive = DateTime.SpecifyKind(user.LastActive, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Pa$$w0rd"); //creates entry and saves changes
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member"); // add member role
            };

            //admin appuser
            var admin = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = "admin"
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync(admin, "Pa$$w0rd");
            await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(admin, new[] { "Admin", "Moderator" });
        }
    }
}
```

In the `DataContext` class, the relationships between `AppUser`, `AppRole` and `AppUserRole` entities are defined using Fluent API. The foreign key constraints and required configurations are set in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>,
    AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserLawn> UserLawns { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(u => u.User)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<AppRole>()
            .HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(u => u.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Lawns) // One AppUser
            .WithOne(ul => ul.User) // One User
            .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId) // Foreign key relationship
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

The related `AppUser` and `AppRole` classes are:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace API.Entities
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime Registered { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public string EquipmentName { get; set; }
        public string EquipmentDescription { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserLawn> Lawns { get; set; } // Navigation property
        public ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace API.Entities
{
    public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>
    {
        public ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity Framework Core (EF Core) is used for data access, and the application uses the `dotnet ef` command-line tool for migrations.

`dotnet ef --version` yields:

```
 Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 7.0.5
```

Identity is configured in program cs in `builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration)`. The `program.cs` class is:

```
using API;
using API.data;
using API.Data;
using API.Entities;
using API.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlite("Data Source=gardeneasy.db");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline

app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000"));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// authentication middleware
app.UseAuthentication();    // valid token?
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// seed users to db
using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope(); //gives access to all services in program cs
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

try
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    await Seed.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
}

app.Run();
```

And the identity service extension class:

```
using System.Text;
using API.Data;
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace API.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<AppRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
                {
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,//check token signing key
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false

                    };
                });
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Versions of the required NuGet packages for Identity, EF Core, and .NET can be inferred from the `API.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.31.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is a single entry in the `AppUserSeedData.json` just in case:

```
[
  {
    "IsActive": true,
    "Picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "Address": "651 Boynton Place",
    "City": "Gorham",
    "Gender": "female",
    "Age": 21,
    "UserName": "Cherry Shaw",
    "Company": "IMAGINART",
    "Email": "cherryshaw@imaginart.com",
    "PhoneNumber": "+1 (958) 515-3793",
    "About": "Amet aute aliqua proident sint exercitation cillum ex quis aute reprehenderit et ipsum. Esse eu nulla nostrud est magna nisi mollit. Dolore id reprehenderit laboris aliqua commodo aute in sit esse aute dolor esse reprehenderit dolor. Aute consequat culpa aliqua laboris reprehenderit cupidatat tempor velit consectetur laborum.\r\n",
    "LastActive": "2019-04-14",
    "Registered": "2014-11-20",
    "Latitude": 28.504291,
    "Longitude": -7.248199,
    "EquipmentName": "commodo",
    "EquipmentDescription": "Anim Lorem consequat aliqua cupidatat aute sunt in reprehenderit anim nostrud reprehenderit pariatur eu tempor. Aliquip nulla laboris veniam sint. Magna et dolor incididunt anim ut culpa eiusmod sunt cillum cillum quis do mollit. Nulla culpa duis aute sit voluptate minim eiusmod Lorem sunt ut sint sint. Mollit officia culpa sunt irure qui est aute minim sunt ut minim cupidatat. Ipsum adipisicing fugiat commodo do adipisicing consectetur id.\r\n",
    "Lawns": [
      {
        "PhotoUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/130.jpg",
        "IsMain": true,
        "Name": "cillum",
        "Latitude": -54.188668,
        "Longitude": -70.029409,
        "Address": "322 Putnam Avenue",
        "LawnSizeInSquareMetres": 21,
        "LastMowed": "2023-05-25"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After defining the model schema for the entities and creating seed data, I first create the migration using `dotnet ef migrations add AddIdentity`.

Thereafter, I run `dotnet run` to apply the migration since my program.cs has the call `await context.Database.MigrateAsync();` that should apply the migration and seed the user data to the database, however this error pops up in the terminal during the migration.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I believe while using Fluent api, `.HasForeignKey( ur=>ur.UserId)` should refer to a UserId field in the AppUserRole that contains values from the Id PK column of the AppUser, hence serves as the FK for the relationship: ```builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles) //app user has many roles
            .WithOne(u => u.User) //appuserrole has one user
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId) //Foreign key in AppUser entity
            .IsRequired();```